# How to not serialize an object based on a property's value?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

If the tags didn't give it away, I'm working with C#'s XmlSerializer class.

Say, for example, I have a Person class with various properties including age (int), name (string), and deceased (bool). Is there a way to specify that I don't want to serialize any objects whose deceased flags are true?

Edit: I should have specified, but unfortunately due to the situation I can't really edit my list of objects because it's a member of another class, which is what I'm actually serializing. Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: So you have an enumeration of `Person` objects? Why not filter out the objects you don't want first?

Comment: That logic would not be best placed in a serialization class, I would think. You should filter your list or array prior to serialization.

Comment: @DavidG I have a list of Persons as a property of another class that I'm serializing, so due to the nature of the situation, I'm not really able to remove things from the list easily.

Comment: Are these list of objects(Person) part of another class which is being serialized? In that case I have a solution for that situation.

Comment: @vendettamit Yes. For example, I have a class called Beings, which contains a list of Animals and a list of Persons. I'm serializing Beings, and the Persons are being serialized as a result of that. But I need to filter certain Persons out of that list during serialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Assuming that you have following type of Class structure(As you specified in the comment)

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Deceased { get; set; }
}

public class Being
{
    public string Data { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Human")]
    public Person Human { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeHuman()
    {
        return !this.Human.Deceased;
    }
}
```

Here I have added a method called `ShouldSerialize` this is called a pattern for XML serialization. Here you can use `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` for lists etc.(With given name) then the `ShouldSerialize` checks if it can be serialized.

Below is the code I used for testing.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var livingHuman = new Person() { Age = 1, Name = "John Doe", Deceased = true };
        var deadHuman = new Person() { Age = 1, Name = "John Doe", Deceased = false };

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Being));

        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, new Being { Human = livingHuman, Data = "new" });

        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, new Being { Human = deadHuman, Data = "old" });
    }
```

> And here's the output:
>   [image]

=============================

> **Update:**

If you have list of Person as Humans:

```
public class Being
{
    // [XmlAttribute]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    // Here add the following attributes to the property
    [XmlArray("Humans")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Human")]
    public List<Person> Humans { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeHumans()
    {
        this.Humans = this.Humans.Where(x => !x.Deceased).ToList();
        return true;
    }
}
```

> Sample Test:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var livingHuman = new Person() { Age = 1, Name = "John Doe", Deceased = true };
        var deadHuman = new Person() { Age = 1, Name = "John Doe", Deceased = false };

        var humans = new List<Person> { livingHuman, deadHuman };
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Being));

        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, new Being() { Humans = humans, Data = "some other data" });
    }
```

> Output:
>   [image]

Comment: The issue is that Human(s) is a List<Person>, not an individual object. Is there a way to make ShouldSerialize work for an individual item in the list?

Comment: I like this method but I' confused as to how it's working. Does the serialiser clone the object before filtering the values?

Comment: This method(ShouldSerialize _propertyName_ ) is optional method for resetting or emitting default value for the property before it gets serialized. see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e(VS.71).aspx). Here I tricked the method to apply filter on values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of `Person` objects and only want to serialise some of them, then just filter out the ones you don't need. For example:

```
List<Person> people = GetPeople(); //from somewhere
List<Person> filteredPeople = people.Where(p => !p.Deceased);
```

Now you only need to serialise `filteredPeople`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really do that due to my situation. See my edit above for the reason why.

Comment: Could you copy the data into another object of some sort?

Comment: I suppose I could create other members of the containing class and set up a couple of ShouldSerialize methods to determine which method I should serialize. I'll have to try that tomorrow.