# XMLSerialize a single element of a list

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I was wondering if it is possible (and IF it has some sort of sense) to xmlserialize a single element of a list.

The serializer is managing a class containing a list of objects (user configurations), but i don't need to save and load always all of them, so I was trying to understand if and how i can save and load only a specific object everytime.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "The serializer manages a list of configurations"? Is this the XmlSerializer you're talking about or is that the WPF part of the question (hence the tag)?

Comment: editing the question to be more specific, thanks

Comment: well there are possibilities, but can you show us what exactly do you want?

Comment: you can control the xmlserialization by using attributes with a special method "ShouldSerialize". See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015080/how-to-not-serialize-an-object-based-on-a-propertys-value/31015970#31015970) if it fits in your scenario.

Comment: But does that methods rewrite the whole serialization, choosing what to serialize and what not? I'd just need to re-serialize a single item of the list, without touching the others