# Conditionally serialize/deserialize attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class whose objects must serialize/deserialize an attribute depending on a bool value

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class Foo
{
    private string myField;
    private bool myFieldSerializes;

    //Parameterless construction for serializing purposes
    public Foo() { }

    public Foo(string myField, bool myFieldSerializes)
    {
        this.myField = myField;
        this.myFieldSerializes = myFieldSerializes;
    }

    public string MyField
    {
        get {return this.myField;}
        set {this.myField = value;}
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MyFieldSerializes
    {
        get {return this.myFieldSerialzes;}
        set {this.myFieldSerialzes = value;}
    }
}
```

This is how it should work:

- If i create an instance and set myFieldSerializes to 'true', when serializing the object (with XMLSerialize), myField must be serialized (included on the XML message). If is set to 'false', it should be ignored.
- When deserializing (with XMLDeserialize), the boolean myFieldSerializes  should tell me if myField has been deserialized (in other words, it was present in the XML file).

What is the way to implement this behavior?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on how you want this to work, but the example code for [XmlAttributre.XmlIgnore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore(v=vs.110).aspx) might be what you want.

Comment: See similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31015970/881798

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your requirements match the *propertyNameSpecified* pattern of `XmlSerializer`.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

> If a schema includes an element that is optional ... [one] option is to use a special pattern to create a Boolean field recognized by the XmlSerializer, and to apply the XmlIgnoreAttribute to the field. The pattern is created in the form of *propertyNameSpecified*. For example, if there is a field named "MyFirstName" you would also create a field named "MyFirstNameSpecified" that instructs the XmlSerializer whether to generate the XML element named "MyFirstName".

What's convenient about this pattern is that, beyond the documented behavior, during deserialization, `XmlSerializer` will set the *propertyNameSpecified* to true if the property was encountered -- which is exactly what you need.  Thus your class should look like:

```
public class Foo
{
    private string myField;
    private bool myFieldSerializes;

    //Parameterless construction for serializing purposes
    public Foo() { }

    public Foo(string myField, bool myFieldSerializes)
    {
        this.myField = myField;
        this.myFieldSerializes = myFieldSerializes;
    }

    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)] // Emit a value even when null as long as MyFieldSpecified == true
    public string MyField
    {
        get { return this.myField; }
        set { this.myField = value; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool MyFieldSpecified { get { return myFieldSerializes; } set { myFieldSerializes = value; } }
}
```

(Adding `[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]` to your `MyField` property ensures that an element will always be emitted when `MyFieldSpecified == true`, even if the field itself is `null`.)

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/awehHu).

Comment: Thanks! In fact, thats the exact case i'm in: an optional attribute in a XSD file that the xsd.exe tool converted into a 'propertyName' and a boolean 'propertyNameSpecified'. I thought I had to manually control the serialization, But I see serializer does all work :)

Comment: Does this work for deserialization too? When I want selectively deserialize properties values from the XML?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can use ShouldSerialize approach:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public bool ShouldSerializeMyField() 
{
      return this.myFieldSerializes;
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go!! I had the same Idea in mind to suggest.

Comment: Here's my detailed post of similar answer for further reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/31015970/881798

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the [ISerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface which allows you to specify what you want to serialize and deserialize.

Therefore you would need to implement an `GetObjectData` method like:

```
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    // Use the AddValue method to specify serialized values.
    info.AddValue("props", myProperty_value, typeof(string));

}
```

and a Constructor which takes `SerializationInfo` and `StreamingContext` as parameters like

```
// The special constructor is used to deserialize values.
public Foo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    // Reset the property value using the GetValue method.
    myProperty_value = (string) info.GetValue("props", typeof(string));
}
```

In this way you can decide **during serialization and deserialization** what to do (e.g. set the value of a propert or not, ...)