# Conditional serialization of property in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have few classes with a number of properties. Value to these properties would be assigned based on certain conditions. After the values are assigned to few of the properties,  I would like to serialize the object and include only those props that have value assigned to them.

I have tried searching for this on Internet but I could not find any luck.

Any suggestion on implementing this would be highly appreciated.

Update:

I have some classes like

```
class A{
        public static string PropA_in_A { get; set; }
        public string PropB_in_A { get; set; }
        public static string PropC_in_A { get; set; }
        public static string PropD_in_A { get; set; }
}

class B{
        public static string PropA_in_B { get; set; }
        public static string PropB_in_B { get; set; }
        public static string PropC_in_B { get; set; }
        public static string PropD_in_B { get; set; }
}

class C{
        public static string PropA_in_C { get; set; }
        public static string PropB_in_C { get; set; }
        public static string PropC_in_C { get; set; }
        public static string PropD_in_C { get; set; }
}
```

Values to the Properties in these classes need to assigned based on conditions.
After the values are assigned , only those properties need to be serialized that have values assigned to them.

```
main()
{
A.PropB_in_A="Some Value";
A.PropA_in_B="Some Value";
A.PropC_in_C="Some Value";
}
```

Here , I would like to serialize only those properties have values assigned to them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xml serialization - Hide null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818513/xml-serialization-hide-null-values)

Comment: You may need to use propertyNameSpecified explained in: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm and duplicated question in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34322765/862795

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XmlElementAttribute on each property and set IsNullable to false.

There is an example on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5).

```
[XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = false)]
public string City;
```

Or use the shorter form:

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = false)]
public string City;
```

EDIT: For nullable value types, you have to jump through some extra hoops and add a property telling the serializer if it should serialize that value.

```
public bool ShouldSerializeMyNullableInt() 
{
  return MyNullableInt.HasValue;
}
```

See this answer for reference: [Xml serialization - Hide null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818513/xml-serialization-hide-null-values)